# Is Order of items read from a XDocument, by LINQ, Guaranteed?

Tags: .net, xml, linq

So what I'm doing is using an xml document to determine the order in which certain SQL scripts need to be ran by a database update.

The XML follows this format

```
<ScriptRules>
    <Database databaseName = “string”>
        <Folder folderPath = “string” executeAllFiles = boolean>
            <file order=”first or last”>“Filename”</file>
        </Folder>
    </Database>
</ScriptRules>
```

So the class that executes all of the `sql` files on the database looks at this at changes it's connection and executes files from folders depending on what the config file has told it to do.

Now my question is this:

Let's say that I have a Document that has 4 `Database` nodes, and each of them have `n` number of `Folder` nodes inside with an assortment of `file` nodes inside of that.

Is it logical of me to assume that if inside of a `For Each` loop over the `Database` nodes that I have retrieved into a `XElement` using `database.Elements("Database")` that they will be pulled in the order that they appear in the xml file? (same for the file nodes)

As far as I have been able to tell this is the case but I just wanted to verify before I start using this on production databases.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, `Elements` returns the elements in document order. From [the docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348975.aspx), in the "return value":

> An `IEnumerable<T>` of `XElement`
>   containing the children of the
>   `XContainer` that have a matching `XName`,
>   in document order.

Comment: do you have a 'Someone asked a question about linq' sense?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, so long as you don't use PLINQ, and even then you can ask it to give you the elements in order.

```
 var orderedCities = (from city in cities.AsParallel().AsOrdered()
                                 where city.Population > 10000
                                 select city)
                                .Take(1000);
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460677.aspx