# Linq to XML Order

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

When reading a XML file with linq to XML using a XDocument and there is no order by on the query can I rely the order in the IEnumerable that is returned ?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3291010/is-order-of-items-read-from-a-xdocument-by-linq-guaranteed

Comment: @BryanCrosby this is a duplicate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

Look at the documentation for [.Descendants()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360635.aspx), for example.  It says that the elements are returned in document order.